# How to access assets directory in a Gradle plugin

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I am currently accessing the assets directory for a project as follows (where `it` has type `Project`):

```
SourceDirectorySet resources = it.sourceSets.main.resources
File file = resources.srcDirs.find { it.name == "assets" }
if (file != null) { ... }
```

Is this guaranteed to be correct? Or is there a better way (probably through `android`)?

Answer (score 0):

In fact the code in the question doesn't work correctly. Instead I needed

```
it.android.sourceSets.main.assets
```