# How to get the asset folder in Gradle plugins

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, android-assets

I am currently writing a Gradle plugin for Android, and one of the tasks needs to analyze the assets to be put in the app. Using the standard directory to the assets `src/main/assets` works for the task, however according to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27425778), it is possible to set different custom sources for assets.

How can one get the correct path to the configured assets folder in an Gradle plugin?

I have already spent a lot of time to read documentation and other questions to figure out the correct way to do so, but have not found a clear answer so far, especially since a good amount of them is out of date.

Most of them (e.g. [How to access assets directory in a Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674090/how-to-access-assets-directory-in-a-gradle-plugin)) reference the `SourceSets` property of the `Project` object, which is no longer part of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of your build.gradle:

```
afterEvaluate {
    println('My Awesome assets folder:')
    android.sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs.each{println it}
}
```